# A strictly increasing, analytic function that goes through key points of the iterated logarithm?

Tags: analytic-number-theory, analytic-functions

Is it possible to create a function $f(x)$ that:

1. is strictly increasing (at least for $x>0$)
2. is real analytic
3. goes through all the points where the iterated logarithm would increment value?

i.e. [for the base-2 version]
$f(1) = 0$,
$f(2) = 1$,
$f(4) = 2$,
$f(16) = 3$,
$f(2^{16}) = 4$, etc.

It feels like this should be possible, but I've had no luck finding such a thing if it exists.

Comment: In other words, you search for an increasing analytic function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}_+^*$ such that $f(1)=0$ and $f(2^x) = f(x)+1$ for all $x>0$?

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan, If I'm not misunderstanding you, then yes, that would be another way to state the problem.

Comment: Don't you want to prescribe values at $2^x$ only for certain *integers* $x$, not for all $x$ ?

Comment: @ChristianRemling Ah, I understand what you are saying. Yes, for the definition that ChristopheLeuridan gave, that only needs to be true for certain integers, (which, if I'm not mistaken are the integer tetrations of the base), but it would be nice if such a definition works for all x, though that doesn't need to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can do this by convolving a first attempt at $f$ with a suitable function to make it analytic. We will then have to keep adjusting our function to achieve exactly the required values at $1,2,4,16,2^{16},\ldots$, and while I think it's "clear" that this can be done (and I hope that what I can offer below is convincing), my nerves are not strong enough to attempt to write down a full fledged rigorous argument for this part.

If $h(t)$ is an increasing function and $|h|$ doesn't get too large as $t\to\pm\infty$, then the convolution
$$
f(z)= \frac{10}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb R} h(t)e^{-50(t-z)^2}\, dt \equiv h*G
$$
is well defined, entire, and increasing on $z=x\in\mathbb R$, as desired. We must still adjust the values at $z=x=1,2,4,2^4,\ldots$.

First of all, let's agree to only work with functions that are odd about $x=1$, so that $f(1)=0$ is already guaranteed. We can start out with a step function $h_1$ of this type that has the required values on symmetric intervals about the above points, so $h_1(x)=1$ on $1<x<3$, $h_1(x)=2$ on $3<x<5$, $h_1(x)=3$ on $5<x<27$ etc. Note that these intervals get longer quickly.

Now I obtain $h_2$ from $h_1$ by adjusting the value on the interval about $2$. Currently $f(2)=(G*h_1)(2)$ is too small, but only slightly, since $h_1=2$ near $x=2$ and $G$ decays rapidly. We give $h_2$ the required value on $1<x<3$ and keep the function odd about $x=1$.

In the next step, we obtain $h_3$ from $h_2$ by also adjusting on the interval about $x=4$. This, however, will ruin the value at $x=2$, so in fact we will also have to change the value near that point one more time. We will have to use the implicit function theorem now to confirm that this can be done. We are in good shape because $f(2)$ is almost independent of $h_3$ near $x=4$ and vice versa, so the Jacobian is almost diagonal and thus non-singular.

We continue in this style and finally converge to a function that we can use as our $h$. Since we only make very slight changes to the initial $h_1$ throughout, the monotonicity is preserved. Also, while the changes on any given interval never stop during the process, they get very small very quickly because for points late in the sequence, $h_1$ has the desired value already on a very long interval, so $G*h_1$ is already extremely close to what we want.